# What happens when my computer locks due to idleness

Tags: login, lock-screen, process

When my computer stays idle for a long time, the screen dims, the computer locks and I'm greeted with the login screen when I resume activity on my computer

My question is what happens to currently running processes when my computer locks?

Answer (score 3):

When your screen locks, your screen locks. No other processes are affected.

Answer (score 2):

The screen you see when resuming activity on your computer looks very much like the login screen, but that doesn't mean that you are logged out of your session.

All programs, every edit task, every document - even a video you were playing (and paused) - everything is there, waiting for you.

The purpose of the lock screen is to prevent others from accessing your content. You can always invoke it manually by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>